# 仕事がたくさんあるが、明日までにできることはできる。でも、ミスが出ないか心配だ。

Tags: meaning

仕事がたくさんあるが、明日までにできることはできる。でも、ミスが出ないか心配だ。

I do not get the part that says ミスが出ないか心配だ
Does that not mean that I am scared of NOT making a mistake, 2 negatives = a positive meaning no mistake?

What would be the difference if it said this instead: ミスが出るか心配だ?

Answer (score 1):

(According to a few mins' reflection) In 'Xか心配だ', X is what you want to happen. So in the case of the example, ミスが出ない is almost always what you want, and 'ミスが出るか心配だ' sounds odd.

As another example, you may or may not want some rain. If you're going on a picnic, you say '雨が降らないか心配だ'. If you are a farmer and there has been no rain for days, then '雨が降るか心配だ'.

---

'X**かと**心配だ' is similar but the above does not (strictly?) apply. 'ミスが出るかと心配だった' sounds quite normal to me, as well as 'ミスが出ないかと心配だった'. (The present tense 'ミスが出るかと心配だ' still sounds slightly odd; Tense doesn't change the acceptability in '**か**心配だ'.)

**[Edit]** Both ミスが{出る/出ない}か心配だった mean *I was afraid there would be mistakes*. ミスが出るかと心配だった sounds that mistakes were 'close' (but did not happen). For example, if you are watching figure skating and the skating is somewhat unstable, then ミスが出るかと心配だった fits better. ミスが出ないか(と)心配だった sound more neutral with regards to the 'closeness'.

---

There are somewhat [similar](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-craindre-avoir-peur-que-ne-expl%C3%A9tif.198124/) [things](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%99%9A%E8%BE%9E#%E8%99%9A%E8%BE%9E%E3%81%AE_ne) in French.

Comment: What does ミスが出るかと心配だった mean in english and what does ミスが出ないかと心配だった mean in English?

Comment: The meaning of both sentences are not very different from ミスが出ない**か**心配だった. See the edit.